# Converting Bezier shape into mesh with nicer topology

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, topology

I have an SVG image of a letter "t" (contains some curved and some straight segments), which has been imported to Blender. After the import, everything is nicely defined as Bezier curves.

Next I want to create a mesh object from this (with the ultimate goal being to try to animate the letter eventually). I have tried using the "Convert to Mesh" command, which results in many triangles and poles. Using the "Decimate" and "Remesh" modifiers also doesn't lead to good results:

[image]

How can I create some nicer mesh topology from this Bezier object (with the ability to add a well-behaved Subdivision Surface modifier as well in the end) ?

File here:

[image]

Comment: actually it all depends on what you want to do afterwards, you're talking about animation, what animation do you want to achieve?

Comment: @moonboots I'd like to be able to do some squash and stretch (to make it look like it jumps). I'd also like to bring the two arms of the "t" forwards (to make it look like it is picking something up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're talking about animation, you could create this kind of topology, which will allow to easily move the parts, rig it and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: I see.  Did you use Convert to Mesh as a first step, then delete lots of stuff? And then add in extra edges using Knife Tool? Can you explain your approach to making this? Thanks!

Comment: Convert to Mesh then some J (join) between the vertices of the opposite edges, Ctrl R to add edge loops along the outer edges to keep the angles sharp...